# how to show multiple Matplotlib in one figure using python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, word-cloud

I have a python script that plot  **histogram**  and **wordcloud** in 2 separate figures.

What i want is to plot these 2 results into one figure.

## code:

```
#plot word count distribution for both positive and negative sentiment
x= def_test_twtr_preds["processed word count"][def_test_twtr_preds.predictions ==1]
y= def_test_twtr_preds["processed word count"][def_test_twtr_preds.predictions ==0]
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
plt.xlim(0,45)
plt.xlabel("word count")
plt.ylabel("frequency")
g = plt.hist([x,y],color=["r","b"],alpha=0.5,label=["positive","negative"])
plt.legend(loc="upper left")

# splt sentence to get individual words
all_words=[]
for line in def_test_twtr_preds["tokens"]: 
    all_words.extend(line)

#create a word frequency dictionary
wordfreq = Counter(all_words)

# #draw a word cloud with word frequencies
wordcloud = WordCloud(width=900,
                     height = 500,
                     max_words=500,
                     max_font_size=100,
                     relative_scaling=0.5,
                     colormap="Blues",
                     normalize_plurals=True).generate_from_frequencies(wordfreq)


fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(17,14))
plt.imshow(wordcloud,interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

To do so, you can use the **subplot** method from **matplotlib**. Have a look at how this "figure 1" is generated https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/multiple_figs_demo.html.

For more complex subplots, have a look at the subplot documentation  https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can't completely rewrite your code since it seems like a good portion of it is missing, but rewriting the plotting section like this should do the trick:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30,30)) # Change to whichever size you want
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax1.set_xlim(0,45)
ax1.set_xlabel("word count")
ax1.set_ylabel("frequency")
g = ax1.hist([x,y],color=["r","b"],alpha=0.5,label=["positive","negative"])
plt.legend(loc="upper left")

# splt sentence to get individual words
all_words=[]
for line in def_test_twtr_preds["tokens"]: 
    all_words.extend(line)

#create a word frequency dictionary
wordfreq = Counter(all_words)

# #draw a word cloud with word frequencies
wordcloud = WordCloud(width=900,
                     height = 500,
                     max_words=500,
                     max_font_size=100,
                     relative_scaling=0.5,
                     colormap="Blues",
                     normalize_plurals=True).generate_from_frequencies(wordfreq)


ax2 = plt.subplot(122)
ax2.imshow(wordcloud,interpolation="bilinear")
plt.show()
```

See @leo-aimone 's

Comment: @Isterzinger if i want to plot more than 2 figures  let say 4 its not like this:
`ax3=plt.subplot(123)
ax3 = plt.barh(words_df['word'], width = words_df['count'])

ax4=plt.subplot(124)
ax4=sns.heatmap(cm, annot=labels, fmt="", cmap='Blues')`

because i got this error :

`ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 2, not 3`